# How do I get Gmail Api to actually import?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am using the Gmail API to try to create a project. And I am using Jupyter Notebook which is an IDE that is run locally in your browser. And in order to use the API, you have to enter a URI in the credentials page in the https://console.developers.google.com/ Google account.

Only then you can use the API. But with Jupyter, the URI changes every time the code is run. I am super confused about what to do to solve this problem. Any advice?

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/173761931313-i8g5p0jknbcjncau2uv8du35cg5ti8a5.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=quickstart-1586630092877&pli=1

Here is the code Gmail provides for Python:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Comment: Which URI are you talking about? The redirect URI for the OAuth consent screen? Also we can not see your GCP project as that is private to your account. Please provide screenshots of what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I experienced a similar issue. I solved it by, creating credentials, type: Desktop App. Then Jupyter Notebook can pass the authorization, and you can select a gmail account to authorize.